# How to combine two SQL queries and selectively display a result

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have two queries which populates two drop down list.

Gets all the **specialties** that are available from the database:

```
string myQuery1 = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE (folder_id IN (SELECT folder_id FROM [content_folder_tbl] WHERE (parent_id = 158) OR (parent_id = 149))) AND (published = 1) AND (UPPER(content_title) NOT LIKE '%DESCRIPTION') AND (UPPER(content_title) NOT LIKE '%IMAGE') ORDER BY content_title";
```

Gets all the **locations** that are available from the database:

```
string myQuery = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE (folder_id = 106) AND (content_type = 1) AND (published = 1) ORDER BY content_title";
```

How do I write a query which will execute the following:

Display the chosen **specialties** that are available from chosen **location**

when the user presses the search button

Comment: Both are in same table?

Comment: Yes. They are both in the table `content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many extra parentheses in your query which are not required. and you can combine where condition from both query and make it single query.

See below query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    content 
WHERE 

    folder_id IN (SELECT 
                    folder_id 
                  FROM 
                    [content_folder_tbl] 
                WHERE 
                    parent_id in (158, 149)) AND 
    published = 1 AND 
    UPPER(content_title) NOT LIKE '%DESCRIPTION' AND 
    UPPER(content_title) NOT LIKE '%IMAGE' AND
    folder_id = 106 AND 
    content_type = 1 AND 
    published = 1 
ORDER BY 
    content_title
```

Comment: I executed the following query in SQL management studio and I got no result. I think I should put it in the ASP.NET to see result I am guessing? I am using a form in my ASP.NET page where the user selects the choices from the dropdown list and presses GO and the next page should display the data.